What causes the Commodore 1581 drive to malfunction when it and a cassette deck are both plugged into a Commodore 64?
At 14:46, in this 8-Bit Show and Tell video, a bug is demonstrated with the 1581 diskette drive on the Commodore 64: if you plug in a cassette deck at the same time and merely push play then stop, you can no longer access the 1581.
According to Is there any existing hardware mod for C64 to decouple tape drive from IEC (1581 drive collision)? it apparently does not happen with the 1571 drive, nor does it happen with a 1581 drive on a Commodore 128.
According to this schematic, the CASS RD line on the cassette interface is shared with the /SRQIN line on the serial bus, though I don't see how that would cause this particular problem given that it doesn't appear to have been used in the demonstration of the bug in the video. (He never tried to read from the cassette deck, just pushed the play and stop buttons. That would generate signals on the CASS SENS line, but that has no connection to the serial bus.)
So what exactly is causing the problem here?

@TonyM My understanding is that it's generally considered poor taste on SEs to edit questions simply to change trivial style details that don't suit you, when they don't affect the meaning of the question. E.g., to change "14:46" to "14m14s" (which by the way is not how YouTube displays or parses timestamps). Thus I've reverted your edit.

Actually, I only (1) edited for a typo, 'plush' to 'push'. While there, I (2) capitalised Play and Stop as they're labels. Finally, on Save, I noticed (3) the 14:46 (just after quarter to three on every digital clock) could have clearer notation (readers here won't see YouTube yet) so I added common notation. So your guess at motives is hopelessly wrong and assumes the very worst. You'd saw a typo correction in edit changes but sadly not thought that my motive. Pity you'd not just posted a friendly comment, for that good SE behaviour. Instead you went into one in a comment...poor taste indeed.

I didn't even notice the "plush" typo fix in your edit, since you'd done so much other stuff. That's a fair edit and I've fixed it. As for the rest, I disagree with you. Pity you didn't just post a friendly comment, or think about the fact that I had carefully considered whether "play" and "stop" should be capitalised or not, and decided not. Regardless, while I'm open to argument on that one, I strongly object to using a different format from YouTube for YouTube timestamps, regardless of whether someone's "see[n] YouTube yet."

And from your description, it appears I attributed your motives correctly: "style details that don't suit you." If you don't like the comment, I'm sorry, but it's my only way here to communicate with you so you know why your edit was rolled back.

Sorry, just reads like you're angrily digging in deeper. People edit typos/grammar all the time here: that's why there's an 'edit' option. I see/get very few rollbacks or rejected edits. When they do, they post a friendly comment/edit note. You could have too, being kind costs you nothing. "I didn't even notice the "plush" typo fix in your edit, since you'd done so much other stuff" You're kidding, right? I edited 9 of 880 characters :-) "it's my only way here to communicate with you" Why not try friendly, peaceful and assuming the best in others? It's free and usually feels great.

Maybe a "Thanks for the typo fix but I've put the rest back the way I like it" comment would have done fine.

@TonyM Don't worry; you have left me completely convinced that you think I am both utterly wrong in not liking your changes, and that I am utterly wrong to have any preferences of my own that are inconsistent with yours, rather than just thanking your for your magnanimous corrections to my feeble errors. I totally understand that you believe it's absolutely my fault if you're offended in any way, and that any offense I should take is simply wrong.

I'm just a passer-by in this fight, but 14:16 is a perfectly reasonable of expressing a duration of 14 minutes and 16 seconds, and even the one that comes naturally to me - so changing that to some other representation is gratuitous. "Common notation" is in the eye of the beholder. And the capitalization was just "meh". My position in general is that, unless the text is egregiously wrong, author prevails. Even when my taste is obviously superior :-)

This is the first case in which I might favor "moving these comments to chat".  There's never a moderator around when you want one, and then three come along at once.

@cjs (1) it was never about you wanting to revert edits. (2) It was about how you communicate it. That's clear in all I've written but I don't think you're seeing that from your replies. (3) On you getting 'offended': there's no place for that here. You can see this isn't your private diary or private property, you chose instead a public posting on a public website. It provides its group with communication and edits. People try to help with unintendeds like typos and grammar. Rest can be politely declined. Your comments read as angry attack, which is a pity to see here. I'll leave you to it.

@dave Indeed, this comments thread is not the best place for my initial message (much less many following it). I would have put my first message in chat had I seen any way of doing that. I debated leaving no indication of why I'd reverted the edit, and I thought that would have been rather unfriendly. I would be pleased to have a moderator move every comment here into chat.

@dave, not a 'fight', no winner can come of this. "changing that to some other representation is gratuitous" etc You skipped the typo, which was all I went in for. As I've said (so many times here), it's not about the reverted edits (which put the typo back, strangely). It's the manner in which was communicated to me: very critical at first and much worse later. Communicating well, basic 'Be nice' policy, ranks above everything on these sites, and in life in general. Not everyone sees that, unfortunately. So much discussion got so little progress back. Anyway, no further action needed.

Fixing a typo is good, but why go beyond that?  And I chose the word "fight" because that is what it looked like to this reader.

@dave, many, many do - that's why we can Edit, why SE looks much better than it would otherwise (look around SE for more on that). But that's irrelevant. Disagreements will arise, it's how they're handled that's paramount. Be Nice. ('Fight': strange. That's hitting people, not typing.)

The issue is possibly related to the shared CASS RD and /SRQIN line, my evidence for this being that the issue apparently doesn't occur on the Commodore 128 and, as you can see from this schematic, the C128 adds a buffer between /SRQIN and CASS RD that prevents CASS RD from driving the /SRQIN line.
That said, it's unclear to me why this would be a problem anyway, unless the cassette unit is doing something weird such as driving the CASS RD line when the play button isn't pressed. From my understanding of the high-speed serial bus protocol using /SRQIN, that line should be ignored by peripherals when /ATN is not asserted.

The cassette on the C64 shares some memory with the serial modem output (check the programming guide for which byte gets double use as both output and some flag for the casette). To use both, a small assembly routine was used to wait for the byte to be zero (all data sent). I'd believe the 1581 could easily have the same sort of software problem.
